# Form is shown in Visual Studio testing, but not when opening Excel template

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I have an .xlt (Excel template) file where I have the following event handler:

```
Private Sub ThisWorkbook_New() Handles Me.[New]
    Dim loginForm As New LoginForm
    loginForm.Show()
End Sub
```

When testing file in Visual Studio, the loginForm shows when the file is opened just like it should.  However, if I open the file outside Visual Studio, the form does not appear.

Does anyone know why this would happen?  My only idea is that when I open the file outside VS, the Excel template loses all the references to the other project files, such as ThisWorkbook.vb where the event handler is located.

Comment: How can the code you provided help?

Comment: @CrushSundae It's the only code that is relevant to displaying the loginForm object and it works in VS, but not outside of it.  Would some other information be more helpful?

Comment: I don't think Excel understands `ThisWorkbook_New() Handles Me.[New]` also ThisWorkbook doesn't make sense for a template. Are you trying to show a form whenever a new workbook is opened in excel?

Comment: @JReid I was following the directions at this [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8553caee.aspx).  In the Comparison section, it says that an Excel template raises the `New` event when opened.  Yes, I'm trying to show a form when the template/workbook is opened.

Comment: From an Excel POV, a template file does that via the Workbook_Open method. It would sound as if ThisWorkbook.vb is not referenced by your template at all. You can add it in the macro editor through Tools->References, that may be all you need to do.